# Multiple input value length validate with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to validate multiple input field length, it is working fine only with one field. I want it to be check all the field with same input name, when the length is same then remove the disabled class from next step button.

This is my code...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input[name="date[]"]').keyup(function() {
    var DoB = [];
    $(".date").each(function(){
      DoB.push($(this).val());
    });
    if (DoB.length == 10) { 
      $('#stepname').removeClass('disabled');
    }
    else {
      $('#stepname').addClass('disabled');
    }
  });
```

```css
.disabled{
   cursor: no-event;
   color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="date" name="date[]">
<input type="text" class="date" name="date[]">

<a href="#" id="stepname" class="btn disabled">Next Step</a>
```

I hope you understand my question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i've understood your question, this should be the right solution for you. ;)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input[name="date[]"]').keyup(function() {
   var disabled = false;
    $('input[name="date[]"]').each(function(key, element){
     if(element.value.length < 10) disabled = true;
    });
    (disabled) ? $('#stepname').addClass('disabled') : $('#stepname').removeClass('disabled');
  });
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  cursor: no-event;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="date" name="date[]">
<input type="text" class="date" name="date[]">

<a href="#" id="stepname" class="btn disabled">Next Step</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is occurred because of new element is not binded with key-up event. you should bind key-up event on document reference.

Please try:-

```
<input type="text" class="date" name="date[]">
<input type="text" class="date" name="date[]">

<a href="#" id="stepname" class="btn disabled">Next Step</a>

.disabled{
   cursor: no-event;
   color: #ccc;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on("keyup", 'input[name="date[]"]', function() {
      var DoB = [];
           $(".date").each(function(){
               DoB.push($(this).val());
            });
    if(DoB.length == 10) { 
      $('#stepname').removeClass('disabled');
    }
    else {
     $('#stepname').addClass('disabled');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`DoB.length` will give you the length of the array. Thus the current condition will not determine whether all the values are same or not.

You can check whether each item in the array are same or not with `every()`. Also I prefer `map()` and `get()` to generate the array from the element's value.

You are also missing `});` at the end.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input[name="date[]"]').keyup(function() {
    var DoB = $(".date").map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    var isTrue = DoB.every(v => v === DoB[0]);
    if(isTrue) { 
      $('#stepname').removeClass('disabled');
    }
    else {
      $('#stepname').addClass('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.disabled{
   cursor: no-event;
   color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="date" name="date[]">
<input type="text" class="date" name="date[]">

<a href="#" id="stepname" class="btn disabled">Next Step</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too; simple and short:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('input[name="date[]"]').keyup(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-ln", this.value.length>=10?"ok":"");
    if ($('input[name="date[]"]:not([data-ln="ok"])')[0]) $('#stepname').addClass('disabled');
    else $('#stepname').removeClass('disabled');
  });
});
```

```css
.disabled{
   cursor: no-event;
   color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="date" name="date[]">
<input type="text" class="date" name="date[]">

<a href="#" id="stepname" class="btn disabled">Next Step</a>
```

---

The problem in your solution is this: `DoB.length` equals 2 always.

also, in your answer for per input's `keyup` you check all input's length which it is not necessary.